# Is there any use of SIP on top of TOR

Tags: sip, tor, privacy

Does it make any sense it terms of perfomance and latency?As far as i know TOR is a transports layer protocol trying to encapsulate the cells with onion routing in order to enhanse privacy.Since sip is widely used as a session protocol for voip calls what do you believe about perfomances of that incarnation?

Answer (score 3):

I made my thesis this year, whose subject was SIP over Tor. Soon you will be able to read a paper we prepare about this.

To the point, I made measurements of delay when using SIP over Tor and I could say the results where quite interesting. Both caller's and callee's servers should use Tor, so if they have a really fast internet connection, then delay is not as much as you think.

The real problem of SIP is that in a call establishment, many untrusted proxies, may intervene. This is where you need a privacy protection system, like Tor.

Let's suppose, Bob wants to call Alice. His smartphone is using Orbot to connect to the Tor Network. Alice is registered to a Server A. If Server A uses Tor for his connections, then he will retransmit the INVITE message to Alice, through Tor. After that, Alice will response to the last Tor node, who sent the request. In this case, both sides are protected, while only the caller and callee's Server use Tor.

As everyone knows, Tor works only on TCP while VoIP services work on UDP and that offers a slightly longer delay. But this delay in real action is NOT noticeable. In addition, Tor will be used only on Call establishment. After the call is established, users can talk to each other without using Tor. It's not that reasonable to use Tor in a direct "user to user" connection.

Comment: i would like to see your report

Comment: @Jack What is the point of using Tor for establishment but not communication? What use-case would it be useful to have only anonymous call establishment but you loose anonymity once you begin communicating?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Well, the implementation of SIP over Tor exists and works nice, this was my answer to the exact question.I guess someone could use Tor even for communicating, but this would not lead to efficient calls between the users (consider a group call with more than 2 users). Our security concern was that during the call's establishment many untrusted proxies will intervene and can obviously see the content of SIP packets, while we don't want them to.

Comment: I see, the threat model was to protect a unsecured handshake, not prevent backtracking of the caller, that makes sense.

Comment: @curious http://www.icsd.aegean.gr/publication_files/conference/314865552.pdf 
I promised you a report. Here is the article, which I will present to ARES conference this september.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that just using TOR for SIP (and not for actual data) isn't good for anonymizing your connection.

Using voip over TOR is definitely foolish, because TOR is slow by it's nature. Your traffic will go through multiple nodes, some being normal home broadband connections. Each connection adds latency, in my experience with rather much (latencies over 200ms are more than common, and it's not my end).

Performance (bandwidth) really depends on your luck. You may get fast connection, or may not. And it also changes regularly, so fast connection may change to horribly slow. Remember that your connection is as slow as slowest link between you and exit node.

Comment: What else is beeing used to provide anonymity to voip traffic?

Answer (score -1):

I started Asterisk VoIP server over OpenVPN in Tor hidden service. It's working with 1s delay.

First create OpenSSL CA with Easy-RSA or OpenSSL for OpenVPN.

This is OpenVPN server configuration file:

```
tls-server
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca /etc/ssl/ca.crt
cert /etc/ssl/server.crt
key /etc/ssl/server.key
dh /etc/ssl/dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
max-clients 100
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
log /var/log/openvpn.log
log-append /var/log/openvpn-append.log
verb 3
auth SHA512
```

This is OpenVPN client configuration file:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote svntrqfgsa7jgnpm.onion 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /home/norbert/new/ca.crt
cert /home/norbert/new/demo-alice.crt
key /home/norbert/new/demo-alice.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
verb 3
socks-proxy 127.0.0.1 9050
remote-cert-tls server
```

This is Asterisk sip.conf configuration file:

```
[general]
transport=udp
port=5060
bindaddr=10.0.0.1
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=gsm
directmedia=no
nat=yes
localnet=10.0.0.0/255.255.0.0

[friends_internal](!)
type=friend
host=dynamic
context=from-internal
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=gsm

[demo-alice](friends_internal)
secret=password

[demo-bob](friends_internal)
secret=password
```

This is Asterisk extensions.conf configuration file:

```
[from-internal]
exten=>6001,1,Dial(SIP/demo-alice,20)
exten=>6002,1,Dial(SIP/demo-bob,20)
```

This is Tor hidden service server torrc configuration file:

```
HiddenServiceDir /usr/local/torhs/winternight/
HiddenServicePort 1194 127.0.0.1:1194
```

This is Tor client configuration file:

```
SOCKSPort 9050
```

That's all. It's working with 1s delay.

Documented in these tutorials:

- https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13595/how-to-setup-asterisk-voip-server-over-openvpn-in-tor-hidden-service-on-freebsd
- https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/59190/

Enjoy. :)

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.